# Is this sentence correct on articles?

Tags: articles

Here are the two sentences where I have a doubt.

1. I had headache.
   or
2. I had a headache.

Comment: In your question, you ask if **this** sentence is correct.  That means one question.  But you then provide two sentences.  Which one do you think is correct?

Comment: What is unclear about the answers to your earlier question? http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16688/why-a-is-used-here-in-the-sentence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's already answered in your previous [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16688/i-had-headache-or-i-had-a-headache), the correct usage of the sentence will be "I had a headache". Since headache is a countable noun, you should add 'a' before the noun, headache in this case.