# Should we use an article (a, the) before Business (noun)

Tags: articles, countability

Please let me know should we use an article (a, the) before Business (noun). Please find the example sentences and let me know your valuable feedback.

**Examples:**

It goes into business as well.

He is running business.

**Or these should be like this:**

It goes into a business as well.

He is running a business.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Where "business" is being used in a similar context to "company" or "organisation", and as such is countable, you need to make sure you use an article.

> It goes into **the** business as well.
>   He is running **a** business.

Or:

> He has been running **the** business since day one.

So both of your phrases above require an article.

However, the term "business" can also be used as a concept, describing trade ([see its various definitions](http://thefreedictionary.com/business)). In this case it is an uncountable (conceptual) noun, and so no article is needed.

> Business is going well at Blah Blah Blah Inc's Headquarters.

Answer (score 2):

Business can be used as either a **countable** noun or an **uncountable** noun.

Your examples should be written,

> It goes into **business** as well.
>   He is running **a business**.

As I said once in [another answer of mine](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/16691/3281), most dictionaries give the definitions without saying anything about a noun being countable or uncountable. However, some dictionaries do. To check the countability of a noun online, I recommend [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com) and [Collins Dictionaries](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/).

You can consult, for example, Macmillan about the word **[business](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/business)**.

The *business* in *"It goes into business as well."* is defined in sense 1,

> **business**
>   noun /ˈbɪznəs/
>   1 [uncountable] the work of buying or selling products or services for money
>   *representatives from business and politics*
>   **do business with someone**: *I found them very easy to do business with.*
>   **go into business**: *It was a mistake to go into business with my brother.*

The *business* in *"He is running a business."* is defined in sense 2,

> 2 [countable] an organization that buys or sells products or services for money. This word often refers to a small organization that is owned and run by one person or a few people, while company can also refer to large organizations
>   *a small family business*
>   *Matthew's little shop has turned into a thriving business.*
>   *Many small businesses fold (=fail) in their first year.*
>   **run a business:** *Sheryl's parents run a small clothing business.*
>   **start your own business:** *After leaving school, Bob started his own computer business.*

There are many other example sentences that could help you understand the different senses of words in both of the two dictionaries.

Comment: To choose between definite and indefinite article when *business* is used as a countable noun, and to choose between definite article (*the*) and no article when *business* is uncountable is something too broad to discuss in one question. You could ask a specific case in a specific context, case by case, as separate questions, though.